# Undefined Index persists although index exists

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4

So basically I wanted to create a list array which goes somewhat like this

```
Array("Region")
 ['id'] => 1
 ['city'] => Array()
```

So from the database I get the Region this way:

```
$regions = Region::get()->keyById()->toArray();
$cities = City::get()->toArray();
```

Then

```
foreach($city as $city)
{
  $regions[city['region_id']]['cities'][] = city;
}
```

This works halfway, when I use `var_dump` on `$region[index]`, it shows as expected both `id` and `city`

```
[0]=>
 ['id'] => 1
 other_contents
 ['city'] => Array()
```

So does `var_dump` on `$region['city']` returns its appropriate content array.

```
Array("Region")
 ['id'] => 1
 ['region_id'] => 1
 other_contents
```

However, when I `var_dump-ed $region['id']`, it returns an `Undefined index: id` instead.

Table structure

```
Region
 id
 other_content

City
 id
 region_id
 other_content
```

Comment: I really cannot make it clear, show you table structure.

Comment: `$regions[city['region_id']]['cities'][] = city;` - that won't work unless you defined the constant `city` anywhere. If you did not: try to use a `$` before the name of a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error lie in this code,

```
  $regions[city['region_id']]['cities'][] = city;
```

$regions is an array of $region, the array index is 0, 1, 2, not the region_id

You can change to this

```
$regions = Region::get()->keyById()->toArray();
foreach($regions as $region)
{   
    $region['cities'] = City::where('region_id', $region->id)->get()->toArray();
}
```

But I recomend you use laravel one to many eloquent.

add this to Region model

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->hasMany('City', 'region_id');
}
```

add this to City model

```
public function region()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Region', 'region_id');
}
```

Then in your controller you can use

`$region->cities()` to get all the cities in the region.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I would consider that. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: thanks a lot, we've decided to try this approach, this would be a great help, thanks ^^